# display:left Staircase bug on google chrome

Tags: css, woothemes

I have spent hours on this issue.
I know it has something to do with float:left, and display:inline-block.
I have tried clearfix. And it is just not working.

I have even removed all files in  in element inspector. it is still showing the staircases. below is the link, this page is based on wordpress default template, I added [featured_products per_page="12" columns="4" orderby="date" order="desc"] on this page.

```
http://101.0.116.204/~vomcom/wp/months-resources/
```

I want to make it look this:

```
http://101.0.116.204/~vomcom/wp/product-category/books/
```

I am using wootheme canvas theme

Many many thanks if somebody can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Carlos suggested, adding line-height 0 to the container addresses the issues, though you're faced with another issue (children inheriting the line-height - the "Sale" tag, for instance).

What seems to be the issue is the `<pre>` tag that wraps your `<ul>`. Changing that to a `<div>` (or just removing it) addresses the float/staircase issue. In addition, your markup will be valid (since [`pre` tags should contain phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)).

Comment: I made sure the childen inherinting the line-height does not mess up the markup haha I always check on that, sometimes causes trouble.

Comment: <Pre>! thats right! I accidently selected pre in visual editor. that's why it is not working! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
ul.products{
    line-height: 0;
}
```

It will look like the desired link.

You still have to do some work to make it look equal, if you need different `line-height` in the children of this element just set it :)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS paths of ul.products are very different from one page to the other.

Path of correct layout:

```
#main > ul
```

Path of broken layout:

```
#main > article > section > pre > div > ul
```

Since editing every single class to find this individual problem is an endless task (due to the huge amount of classes involved), I suggest you to completely delete the problematic page, copy the correct page into a new one, then edit that page to show the contents you want, and be careful not to add useless objects, divs or classes.